# UIPageViewController resets to first page on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

When the user rotates their device, the `UIPageViewController` fades from whatever page it is displaying back to the first page. This is really annoying, especially when the user is multiple pages into the document. It only occurs in iOS 6.

When the user rotates their device, `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` is called, which probably has something to do with the issue.

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
               spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;

}
```

I always want the spine to be on the left.

Do you have any idea what is causing the `UIPageViewController` to reset? I found a bug report [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/12745144), but I have been unable to find any other information online, leaving me to think that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` is incomplete

it should be something like this:

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
                   spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

        UIViewController *currentViewController = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = @[currentViewController];
        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

        return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can you just explain your syntax to me? I can tell that `@[currentViewController];` allocates a new `NSArray` and adds `currentViewController` as its only object (`[[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:currentViewController];`). I've never seen `@[]` before; can this be used for other classes?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just copied the code from the UIPageViewController xcode template, but it seems for NSArrays only

Comment: In an earlier sample project where I used the UIPageViewController template, that line was NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];, now the samples use the new syntax, but I have only seen this with NSArrays

Comment: @jcesar In case someone comes looking and is unsure, this `@[]` is the new literal syntax for obj-c.  This http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/ covers a lot of the new literal syntax.

Comment: This didn't work for me when going from portrait to landscape on iOS 6.1. pageViewController.viewControllers[0] was already reset to the initial view controller by the time this callback gets called. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188592/uipageviewcontroller-first-rotation-resets-views-to-initial-page has a workaround which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that such a bug exists, but worst case scenario, you could override

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

to capture the old state and re-set it after the transition is done. I'm tempted to believe there's something else causing the issue, but without more data, I can't tell. Can you post more of the UIPageViewController code?

Comment: This worked for me, as I persist state in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and used in spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I found simply removing my implementation of `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't an ideal solution.