# UIPageViewController - first rotation resets views to initial page?

Tags: xcode, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to understand Apple's default template for a Page-based application. That template shows a sort of calendar with one page for each month of the year.

When compiling the template without any changes, I noticed something odd. When the app launches, it displays in portrait mode, and when - after flipping through some of the pages (say, to June) - you change the rotation, it reloads in landscape mode showing two pages, BUT STARTING WITH JANUARY. This happens only once, though. On subsequent orientation changes, it then jumps to the correct "currentViewController".

The code for this seems to come from the RootViewController file, specifically

```
UIViewController *currentViewController = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
```

And frankly, it seems to be ignored for the first orientation change.

I am trying to understand why?

Comment: Interesting! This only happens in iOS6. When running in the 5.1 simulator, the exact same code executes correctly. I've set a Breakpoint and notice that in 5.1, the function `- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation` is NOT executed when the UIPageviewcontrol first loads, but in 6.0 it is.

Comment: Check this out

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132132/uipageviewcontroller-resets-to-first-page-on-rotation

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this thread before I posted, but this isn't related to what I posted I think. I am using the default page based template from Apple without any changes, and the rotation bug only happens on the very first orientation change (and only in iOS6). It works fine on subsequent orientation changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to deal with the same issue when updating an App to be iPhone 5 friendly. When compile with iOS 6 sdk, the problem appear on iOS 6, but not on iOS 5. It happens only when entering the PageViewController from landscape orientation.

A workaround :

Create a property to save the current state in @interface section of your .m :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *viewControllersSave;
```

Save the viewControllers in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` :

```
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // some code here...
    self.viewControllersSave = self.pageViewController.viewControllers;
}
```

Use the saved property instead of the PageViewController property in `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation`.

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController: (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
                   spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
   // some code
   NSArray *viewControllers = @[self.viewControllersSave[0]];
   [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                            direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                            animated:YES
                            completion:NULL];

return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}
```

This could be a possibility to avoid the problem BUT you should submit a bug report to Apple to avoid such a workaround for later usage.

Comment: Thanks!!! It didn't cut it for me out of the box, as I kept getting SIGABRT's until I moved the code from `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. I also changed it slightly and instead of saving to an array, I declare `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewControllerSave;` and save `self.viewControllerSave = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];` which has the benefit of working with my `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation`code in both landscape and portrait. I accept your answer since it pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for acceptation, you should not execute any other code than the one who compute the supported orientations in supportedInterfaceOrientations.

Comment: Why not? From the Apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html - _Use rotation notifications to update your app’s state information. If your app uses the current orientation to determine how to present content, use the rotation methods of your view controller (or the corresponding device orientation notifications) to note those changes and make any necessary adjustments._ Like I said, the code you suggested crashes in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: This docs read that you should use notifications and/or rotations methods (like willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation / didRotateRotateFromInterfaceOrientation...)
There is no concrete reason not to do this, this is just for better code design